# How should one pass columns as variables or indexes to tidyr::separate

Tags: r, tidyr

Getting errors while trying to pass columnames as indexes or variables to `tidyr::separate`.

Setting up libraries & data:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(col1 = 1:4,
                col2 = c("a,b,c","d,e,f","g,h,i","j,k,l"))
sep <- ","
colnameVar <- "col2"
```

These work (in dplyr):

```
x %>% select(col2) %>% names
# [1] "col2"
x %>% select(colnameVar %>% as.name %>% eval) %>% names
# [1] "col2"
x %>% select(2) %>% names
# [1] "col2"
```

As does this (with separate):

```
x %>%
 separate(col2,
 paste("col2",1:3,sep="."),
 sep = sep) %>% names
# [1] "col1"   "col2.1" "col2.2" "col2.3"
```

But this fails:

```
x %>%
 separate(colnameVar %>% as.name %>% eval,
 paste("col2",1:3,sep="."),
 sep = sep) %>% names
```

> Error: Invalid column specification

As does this:

```
x %>%
 separate(2,
 paste("col2",1:3,sep="."),
 sep = sep) %>% names
```

> Error: Invalid column specification

How should this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using underscore version of *separate*, where we can pass strings:

```
# colnames as a predefined string
x %>%
  separate_(colnameVar, paste("col2", 1:3, sep = "."), sep = sep) %>%
  names
# [1] "col1"   "col2.1" "col2.2" "col2.3"

# colnames as index (well almost, we are getting colname as string by index)
x %>%
  separate_(colnames(x)[2], paste("col2", 1:3, sep = "."), sep = sep) %>%
  names
# [1] "col1"   "col2.1" "col2.2" "col2.3"
```